# How to set up Ubuntu to automatically turn NumLock on when an external keyboard is attached and off when it is not?

Tags: gnome, xorg, automation, numlock

Having NumLock on is convenient when using a full-sized external keyboard (having a keypad) and very inconvenient when using laptop's built-in keyboard (which places digits instead of letters on the keyboard's right sid unless Fn is pressed).

So I have to turn NumLock on every time I attach an external keyboard (or boot with it attached) and off every time I detach an external keyboard (or boot with it detached). And I do this frequently because I prefer using a full-sized external keyboard, but have not enough (only 3) USB ports to plug-in it alongside with a mouse, a 3G modem and an external hard/flash drive.

Can I automate this? Seems a very formaliseable, logically simple task: if there is an USB keyboard attached (some device in /dev present?) - NumLock is on, if not - NumLock is off. My laptop's built-in keyboard is PS/2-attached, external is USB.

Maybe I should code it myself, but where to put it in this case?

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, install numlockx ([click here to install numlockx](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/numlockx)). Basically this allows you to write scripts to set the state of Num Lock - see the [numlockx man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/numlockx.1.html) for details.

Next we need to start delving into the fun of udev rules. First we need to find out how the keyboard is identified. You can do this by

```
ls /dev/input/by-id/
```

This should give you some human readable file names (that are soft links to the not particularly readable true name). My keyboard was

```
/dev/input/by-id/usb-KINESIS_FREESTYLE_KB700_KB700_Kinesis_Freestyle-event-kbd
```

So then we need to find out all the info about the keyboard. I did

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/by-id/usb-KINESIS_FREESTYLE_KB700_KB700_Kinesis_Freestyle-event-kbd)
```

But insert your own path there of course. You'll get a lot of info, but you want to look at the first block that names the keyboard and has `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`. (Rather than the USB controller or whatever). In my case that was:

```
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.3':
    KERNELS=="3-2.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}==" 50mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="6284"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9410"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0122"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{speed}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2.3"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="KINESIS FREESTYLE KB700"
    ATTRS{product}=="KB700 Kinesis Freestyle"
```

So now we have enough information to write some rules. Use your favourite editor to create `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` and put in:

```
BUS=="usb",ATTRS{product}=="KB700 Kinesis Freestyle",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/usr/bin/numlockx on"
BUS=="usb",ATTRS{product}=="KB700 Kinesis Freestyle",ACTION=="remove",RUN+="/usr/bin/numlockx off"
```

Again, put the name of your keyboard in here, and the ATTRS if it is different. Then it should work :)

Note I haven't been able to test this, though I have run all the commands up until creating the rules file. And the sources in case you need to do some more investigation are:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221
- http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run

Comment: Thanks a lot, excellent. To be honest, I didn't expect to get an answer any close to such informative. I'd wish I could award it more than just correct and +1. I hope all those who has starred and voted for my question will also award you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gnome3 shell.

Install numlockx

then launch Startup application preferences `gnome-session-properties`

[Image (new users can't post images :))](http://postimage.org/image/294b5v544/)

Click Add

Write anything into name field and into command field copy this:`numlockx on`

[Image](http://postimage.org/image/2946793ms/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I'm doing differently, because my numlock on this keyboard is defaulting to on (This is a Mac Pro Aluminum keyboard). There are some [instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) that should do the trick.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If are you using gnome-shell, then you could install Numlock & Capslock status on the panel "Lock Keys" extension. Please, found it [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/)