# Why is my Laptop keyboard messed up after plugging an external keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, numpad

I'm running xubuntu 12.04 on a 2007 macbook.

I'm using the laptop with external screen, keyboard and mouse.
Yesterday after a dist-upgrade and after I unplugged the external keyboard I noticed that the Lapotop's keyboard was mapped to whatever (J = 1 , L = 3 , M = 0 e.t.c.) however I can login and type perfectly in the login screen and as a guest.

Any suggestions on how to get more information and/or troubleshooting are welcome.

Comment: Could be related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5140/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-to-automatically-turn-numlock-on-when-an-external-keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like your Laptop keyboard has an **integrated Numpad**. It is active when enabling NumLock.
Your Laptop Numpad might have small drawings of numbers on right part of your keyboard with the following mapping:
`jkl -> 123`
`uio -> 789`
`m -> 0`

Disabling NumLock should give back those keys their primary function.

1. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> several times to disable Numlock.
   You might also have a combination with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys depending on your Laptop model.
2. If for some reason you are unable to get it done with your physical keyboard, this should help:

   1. execute `onboard` in a terminal. This will open an on-screen keyboard.
   2. click <kbd>123</kbd>, then <kbd>NumLock</kbd>. After every click check if your Laptop keyboard is back to normal.

   [image: NumLock key on the onboard keyboard (after hitting the 123 key)]

**Notes**:

- On Mac keyboards the NumLock button is [likely to be labelled "clear"](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5182).

Comment: there is no numpad on the laptop neither exists a numlock button ()

Comment: Well Ubuntu is seeing one. What about Fn keys? Is there one for NumLock? If not disable the Numlock on the external keyboard.

Comment: nope, unfortanetly macs dont have this kind of things, is there any 'detect keyboard layout and functionality' command?

Comment: So your laptop is a Mac and on the external keyboard you are unable to disble the Numlock? At least the external one should have a Numlock button. On Mac keyboards it is the "clear" button: http://kb.parallels.com/en/5182

Comment: The laptop's keyboard is like this http://lowendmac.com/mail/mb07/art/macbook_keyboard.jpg

Disabling the num pad on the external keyboard does nothing (i can still use the external keyboard numpad and the laptop's keyboard is still messed up) 

(btw thx for the answer :-) )

Comment: At least that jpg show the small numbers of the integrated numpad I have been talking about :). Also try Shift+clear and check if the keyboard comes back. Hit that combination several times if not working the first time.

Comment: thats why I said 'like' :p my keyboard doesnt, anyway it didnt work after several tries.
I'll try searching for the configuration file which should list what it thinks each keyboard is

finally I found an acurate picture of the keyboard 

http://www.sonyvaiopart.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/k/e/keyboard_6.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6158/discussion-between-rosch-and-northpole)

Comment: @rosch - Thank you! Last year, I have installed a distro based on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba laptop. This device worked fine but was left aside for several months. After a long gap, I have connected this laptop to the internet and did the update and upgrade. At the time of this process, the laptop had an external keyboard, mouse and monitor.  Well, now, I have noticed that the keyboard often starts to behave odd. When I want to write, I got new windows opened, tabs closed, etc. I have executed in terminal the command "onboard" and typed just the number "1", and everything went back to normal!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem running Linux Mint. I plugged my external keyboard in again and pressed the numlock key to turn numlock off. Solved!

Comment: It seems to be specifically Cinamon desktop related, since I tested it with MATE and it's working properly. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8912).

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to my problems with my Samsung keypad after it had been used with an external keyboard in which it does not function well. The instructions were given at Ask Ubuntu:

> - Put off the unit with the external keyboard and restart it with the external  keyboard.
> - When the laptop is in the state ready to use, from the external keyboard simultaneously hit the keys NUMLOCK and SHIFT and try to hit a key which is lock before if it is reinstated.